# Getting PID of Process on Windows, OSX and Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, macos, pid

I have a java function that should be fetching the PID of a process and it works on windows

```
public static String executeJps() throws IOException {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jps -l");
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                                    p.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        String pid = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String [] javaProcess = line.split(" ");
            if (javaProcess.length > 1 && javaProcess[1].contains("DEDServer")) {
                pid = javaProcess[0];
            }
        }

        return pid;
}
```

Will that same function get the PID successfully on macs and Linux operating systems and basically all Operating Systems? Or is there something else that needs to be done so another function?

I don't have anything but a windows OS so if you are going to be able to post some new code please can it be verified?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is the same as for the question: does the command `jps -l` exist on the other platforms and does it do the same as on windows?

Comment: jps is part of JDK?  Will there be JDK on all production machines?

Comment: JDK will be on all the machines yes. @Jayan

Comment: That's what I can't find out until someone is able to test it... @A4L

Comment: we jps on Linux. It _should_ be there on osx as well.

Comment: Would you be able to check the code and just verify it works then? Just need to put it in a java function, call the function and print out the `pid` variable. Change the `.contains("DEDServer")` to a process that is running and it should work :) Thanks! @Jayan

Comment: your question is little bit misleading, [jps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html) wont get you the ID of any process. it will only get those of virtual machine instances actually running on a given host.

Comment: @A4L the function I posted gets the PID.

Comment: Your title should have been: _Getting PID of **java** Process on Windows, OSX and Linux_. I assume that `DEDServer` is a java main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication of the jps manual entry is that jps should work on all (Oracle supported) platforms, and that the output format is the same.